# Integrable functions as sums of measures

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \rightarrow [0, + \infty] \mathcal A$-measurable.

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb N \cup \{+ \infty\}$ for all $x \in \Omega$. Why does it hold true that $\int f d \mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu (\{x \in \Omega: f(x) \geq n \})$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu(\{f=\infty\}) > 0$, then of course both sides of the equation equal $\infty$. Otherwise,
\begin{align}
\int f\,d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mu(\{f=n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(\{f=n\}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\mu(\{f=n\}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(\{f\ge k\}).
\end{align}

Comment: Mate, what if $0<f(x)<1$, then your very first equality seems not hold.

Comment: @user284331 What function $0 < f(x) < 1$ satisfies $f(x) \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ for all $x \in \Omega$?

Comment: I didn't notice that, sorry.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks, edited.